# Finding an interval on the set that is not m*-measurable.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, interval-arithmetic

So this is a past paper question that I am struggling with slightly. I have managed to prove that $m^*$ was a measure, which was the preceding the previous part of the question. It is the next part that I am struggling with slightly!

Let $A,B \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be disjoint infinite sets. For any $ E \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ define

$$   
m^*(E) = 
     \begin{cases}
       \text{2,} &\quad\text{if $E$ intersects both $A$ and $B$,}\\
       \text{1,} &\quad\text{if $E$ intersects exactly one of the sets $A$ or $B$}\\
       \text{0,} &\quad\text{if $E \cap A = E \cap B = \emptyset$}\\
     \end{cases}.
$$
For $m^*$ defined above, find an interval $[x,y]$ which is not $m^*$-measurable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to proove that $m^*$ is, in fact, an outer measure.

Now, let $A,B \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be disjoint infinite sets.

Since $B$ is infinite, there are $b_0,b_1,b_2 \in B$, such that $b_0<b_1<b_2$. Since $A$ is infinite then $A\cap (-\infty,b_1)$ or $A\cap(b_1,\infty)$ (or both) is an infinite set.

**Case 1**: Suppose $A\cap (-\infty,b_1)$ is infinite. Then there are $a_0, a_1 \in A$ such that $a_0<a_1<b_1 <b_2$.

Let $I=[a_1,b_1]$. We claim that $I$ is not $m^*$-measurable.

In fact, since
$\{a_1,b_1\}\subseteq I = \mathbb{R}\cap I$ we have

$$  m^*(\mathbb{R}\cap I) =2$$

and since
$\{a_0,b_2\}\subseteq \mathbb{R}\cap I^c$ we have

$$ m^*(\mathbb{R}\cap I^c)=2$$

So we have

$$ m^*(\mathbb{R})=2 < 2+2= m^*(\mathbb{R}\cap I) + m^*(\mathbb{R}\cap I^c)$$

So $I$ is not $m^*$-measurable.

**Case 2**: Suppose $A\cap (b_1,+\infty)$ is infinite. Then there are $a_1, a_2 \in A$ such that $b_0<b_1 <a_1<a_2$.

Let $I=[b_1,a_1]$. We claim that $I$ is not $m^*$-measurable.

The proof is analogous to case 1.

In fact, since
$\{b_1,a_1\}\subseteq I = \mathbb{R}\cap I$ we have

$$  m^*(\mathbb{R}\cap I) =2$$

and since
$\{b_0,a_2\}\subseteq \mathbb{R}\cap I^c$ we have

$$ m^*(\mathbb{R}\cap I^c)=2$$

So we have

$$ m^*(\mathbb{R})=2 < 2+2= m^*(\mathbb{R}\cap I) + m^*(\mathbb{R}\cap I^c)$$

So $I$ is not $m^*$-measurable.